# htaccess with 301 redirect for entire site except one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am using the following code in htaccess to redirect to new domain with 301:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works perfectly. However, with the old domain I would like to keep the sitemap without redirecting. I.e. not redirecting olddomain.com/sitemap.xml . Can I do that by adding something to the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
# do nothing for sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ - [L]
# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

(reminder: order matters, exceptions first)